# Login twitter with username and password, POST java

Tags: java, twitter, authentication, twitter4j

I get OAuthToken, Authenticity Token from the libarary Twitter4j (it is correctly, becouse when I login in browser its works). Then try to login twiiter with password and username with POST request:

```
    URL url = new URL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
```

Add parametrs to request:

```
    String params = "oauth_token" + "=" + oAuthToken;
    params += "&" + "session[username_or_email]" + "=" + login;
    params += "&" + "session[password]" + "=" + password;
    params += "&" + "redirect_after_login" + "=" + "https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + oAuthToken;
    params += "&" + "authenticity_token" + "=" + authToken;

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    OutputStreamWriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.write(params);
    output.flush();
```

get response:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int httpResult = connection.getResponseCode();

    if (httpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        br.close();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("response.html");
        out.print(sb);
        out.close();
        out.flush();

        System.out.println(getVerifier(sb.toString()));

    } else {
        System.out.println("Response: " + connection.getResponseMessage() + ",  Status: " + httpResult);
    }
```

But nothing happens, in response I have HTML page, where I can login twitter.